# Setting up a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was developing a site in a subfolder so the url was look like:

```
www.site.com/website/makeuphair
www.site.com/website/treatment
```

and these URLs have been indexed by search engines.

Now, I am looking for a general rule for .htaccess that can redirect all the URLs inside the /website folder to relevant pages on the main site. That is,

```
site.com/website/makeuphair should
redirect to: site.com/makeuphair

site.com/website/treatment should
redirect to: site.com/treatment.
```

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/website/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Try that one out. Rewrites everything from /website/ to / with a 301 (Moved permanently) header